# Show repeated customer with in 30 days

Tags: postgresql

I would like to display result repeated 3 or more same customer within period of 30 days (V_Date)

so, table would look like

```
     Name      V_Date  
    Arun Kumar 2015-30-01  
    Arun Kumar 2015-31-01  
    Arun Kumar 2015-12-02  
      Vijay    2015-01-01  
      Vijay    2015-28-01  
      Vijay    2015-15-02  
      vinoth   2015-02-01  
      vinoth   2015-02-06  
      vinoth   2015-02-08  
      Anand    2015-01-01  
      Anand    2015-02-02  
      Anand    2015-03-03
```

Expected Output

```
     Name        V_Date  
    Arun Kumar 2015-30-01  
    Arun Kumar 2015-31-01  
    Arun Kumar 2015-12-02  
      vinoth   2015-02-01  
      vinoth   2015-02-06  
      vinoth   2015-02-08
```

currently able to select repeated 3 or more customer using HAVING COUNT(name)>=3 but not unable to check V_Date in 30 days. How to get Expected Output?... based on below condition:-

```
 Arun Kumar (V_Date 31-01-2015 to 12-02-2015) 
             visit (3 or more time) within 30 days

  Vijay      (V_Date 01-01-2015 to 15-02-2015) 
             Not visit (3 or more time) within 30 days

  Vinoth     (V_Date 01-02-2015 to 08-02-2015) 
             visit (3 or more time) within 30 days

  Anand      (V_Date 01-01-2015 to 03-03-2015) 
             Not visit (3 or more time) within 30 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add where statement:

```
....  WHERE (w.deliverydate BETWEEN (NOW() - interval '1 months')::date AND NOW()::date)
```

Then use Having statement
if this is not what you are looking for please be more specific